# Display CSV file contents based on selection in dropdown menu using Flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, csv, flask

In the snippet below, I'm using a responsive dropdown menu for job field and job title and I'm trying to display dynamic content based on which menu item is chosen. I'm unsure what coding that I should write because I want to display from content in CSV file. Where I will have three CSV files, job_it.csv, job_dm.csv, and job_fn.csv. For each CSV file, it contains 4 rows: header(title, location, education, skills, languages, certification, and years experience), job title 1, job title 2, and job title 3. Then, I already create upload page where the user can select what field they want and the title for each field. After clicking the button, it will display the contents from the CSV file on the next page where if they select first title, the page will the display only the second row (row with title 1).

Here is the snippet for HTML, JS and Flask Application:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>UPLOAD FILE</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper2">
        <nav class="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">UPLOAD FILE</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">DETAILS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CLASSIFICATION</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SHORTLISTED</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">ANALYSIS</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <div class="upload">

            <form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              <h3>Choose job's field: </h3>
              <select name="job-field" id="job-field">
                  <option value="" selected="selected">Select field</option>
              </select>
              <br><br>
              <h3>Choose job's title: </h3>
              <select name="job-title" id="job-title">
                  <option value="" selected="selected">Select title</option>
              </select>
              <br><br>
              <h3>Upload a CSV file: </h3>
              <input type="file" name="file">
              <br><br>
              <button type="submit">Upload</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='script.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
var jobInfo = {
    "Information Technology and Software Development": ["Senior Frontend Developer", "Data Processing Specialist", "Java Developer"],
    "Digital Marketing": ["Digital Marketing Web Specialist", "Video Editor", "Graphic Designer"],
    "Finance": ["Financial Analyst-SSC", "Accountant", "Specialist, Business Finance (APAC)"]
}
window.onload = function() {
  var jobField = document.getElementById("job-field");
  var jobTitle = document.getElementById("job-title");
  for (var x in jobInfo) {
    jobField.options[jobField.options.length] = new Option(x, x);
  }
  jobField.onchange = function() {
    //empty Chapters- and Topics- dropdowns
    jobTitle.length = 1;
    //display correct values
    for (var y of jobInfo[this.value]) {
      jobTitle.options[jobTitle.options.length] = new Option(y, y);
    }
    var selectedJobField = this.value;
    var selectedJobTitle = jobTitle.value;

    //display certain information based on selection
      if (selectedJobField === "Information Technology and Software Development") {
        if (selectedJobTitle === "Senior Frontend Developer") {
          console.log("Selected job is Data Processing Specialist in Information Technology and Software Development field.");
          // display more information or perform some action here
        }
        else if (selectedJobTitle === "Data Processing Specialist") {
          console.log("Selected job is Data Processing Specialist in Information Technology and Software Development field.");
          // display more information or perform some action here
        } else if (selectedJobTitle === "Java Developer") {
          console.log("Selected job is Java Developer in Information Technology and Software Development field.");
          // display more information or perform some action here
        }
      } else if (selectedJobField === "Digital Marketing") {
        if (selectedJobTitle === "Digital Marketing Web Specialist") {
          console.log("Selected job is Digital Marketing Web Specialist in Digital Marketing field.");
          // display more information or perform some action here
        } else if (selectedJobTitle === "Video Editor") {
          console.log("Selected job is Video Editor in Digital Marketing field.");
          // display more information or perform some action here
        } else if (selectedJobTitle === "Graphic Designer") {
          console.log("Selected job is Graphic Designer in Digital Marketing field.");
          // display more information or perform some action here
        }
      } else if (selectedJobField === "Finance") {
        if (selectedJobTitle === "Financial Analyst-SSC") {
          console.log("Selected job is Financial Analyst-SSC in Finance field.");
          // display more information or perform some action here
        } else if (selectedJobTitle === "Accountant") {
          console.log("Selected job is Accountant in Finance field.");
          // display more information or perform some action here
        } else if (selectedJobTitle === "Specialist, Business Finance (APAC)") {
          console.log("Selected job is Specialist, Business Finance (APAC) in Finance field.");
          // display more information or perform some action here
        }
      }
     }
}
```

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
import pandas as pd
from scraper import scrape_data
from data_cleaning import clean_data

app = Flask(__name__)
app.static_folder = 'static'

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home_page.html')

@app.route('/upload_page')
def upload_page():
    return render_template('upload_page.html')

# @app.route('/process', methods=['POST'])
# def process():
#    job_field = request.form['job_field']
#    return redirect(url_for('display', job_field=job_field))

@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload():
    job_field = request.form['job-field']
    job_title = request.form['job-title']
    file = request.files['file']
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    data = scrape_data(df)
    cleandata = clean_data(data)
    print(cleandata)
    return render_template('display.html', data=cleandata)

# @app.route('/classify_data', methods=['POST'])
# def process_data():
    # Process data here
#    return render_template('display_classification.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Scraped Information</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">UPLOAD FILE</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">DETAILS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CLASSIFICATION</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">SHORTLISTED</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ANALYSIS</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <h1>{{ job_field }}</h1>
    {% if job_field == 'IT' %}
    <p>Details for Information Technology and Software Development go here...</p>
    {% elif job_field == 'DM' %}
    <p>Details for Digital Marketing go here...</p>
    {% elif job_field == 'FN' %}
    <p>Details for Finance go here...</p>
    {% endif %}

    <h2>Scraped Information</h2>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Title</th>
          <th>Location</th>
          <th>Experiences</th>
          <th>Education</th>
          <th>Certifications</th>
          <th>Skills</th>
          <th>Languages</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {% for item in data %}
        <tr>
          <td>{{ item["Name"] }}</td>
          <td>{{ item["Title"] }}</td>
          <td>{{ item["Location"] }}</td>
          <td>{{ item["Experiences"] }}</td>
          <td>{{ item["Education"] }}</td>
          <td>{{ item["Certifications"] }}</td>
          <td>{{ item["Skills"] }}</td>
          <td>{{ item["Languages"] }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  <form action="/classify_data" method="POST">
    <button type="submit">Classification</button>
  </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

In the JavaScript code, I think I need to replace this code with the right code. But, I don't find the right one.

```
console.log("Selected job is Digital Marketing Web Specialist in Digital Marketing field.");
          // display more information or perform some action here
```